# PySNMP NameError: name 'getCmd' is not defined

Tags: python, pysnmp

I have recently installed PySNMP library on Ubuntu.

http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/quick-start.html

I followed the Quick Start procedure with "Fetch SNMP variable" as explained in the link above.

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error:

```
File "/home/Camille/Desktop/quick_start.py", line 4, in <module>
getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
NameError: name 'getCmd' is not defined
```

getCmd() is a function and it does exist

Comment: Did you forget this at the top of your code: `from pysnmp.hlapi import *`. When I removed that line I replicated your problem. It could be that. Other than that, I have no idea what else could be wrong.

Comment: I only have this error on Ubuntu. It works fine on Raspbian (which is supposed to be my SNMP Agent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a packaging bug in the apt package.

On Mint 17.3 (Ubuntu 14.04), if I create a virtual environment and use pip to install PySNMP, I get version 4.3.2, and this is fine:

```
>>> from pysnmp.hlapi import *
>>> getCmd
<function getCmd at 0x7f24e6fab0c8>
```

*However*, if I install the ubuntu package via `apt-get install python-pysnmp4`, I get 4.2.5, and the above code does not work at all. (`ImportError: No module named hlapi`)

In my case, the apt package version does not include the `hlapi` module.

The file listing of the PySNMP 4.2.5 source code is here: http://pysnmp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pysnmp/pysnmp/pysnmp/?pathrev=release_4_2_5_tag

And the file listing of the apt package is here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/python-pysnmp4/trusty/files/head:/pysnmp/

I don't know why it's missing, but it's either an omission (they forgot the hlapi folder), or some other reason that isn't clear to me.

While this is not the same as your error, it does suggest that there might be other packaging issues. Perhaps the version that you're using is also incomplete in some way.

Bottom line, if you create a virtualenv and use `pip` to install PySNMP, you will probably be ok. You might also want to file a bug with the launchpad maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

When you install pysnmp via:

```
$ pip install pysnmp
```

or

```
$ easy_install pysnmp
```

The library pysnmp is installed in this path:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

that is not one of default path search

In your program add those lines:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```